# Accepting Integer Array from Command Line - C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, command

I need to accept an array of integers from the command line, such as:
./test 2 9 -5 17

Currently I have:

```
int main(int argc, int *argv[])
```

And then loops to find the two numbers within this array that create the maximum value possible starting with argv[1].  Obviously this does not work.  Do I need it to be:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

and then parse this?  I am not sure how to covert characters to integers in C.

Thanks,

Comment: What is the range of acceptable integers?

Comment: _I am not sure how to covert characters to integers in C_.  `atoi()` or `strtol()` will work to convert a string to an int

Comment: There is no range.  Any integers, positive and negative, large/small, are to be accepted.

Comment: JDeffo: "no range. Any integers" --> So values like 123456789012345678901234567890 are acceptable?

Comment: @Mike Holt  OP may want to limit code's operation to integers within the range of some C integer type like `int` of `long long` or maybe not.  It would be illuminating to know OP's thoughts on the coding goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use strtol() to convert each argv[i] (for i starting at 1) to a long int.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    size_t i;
    int n;

    for (i = 0; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &n) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Position %d is not an int\n", i + 1);
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

    return 0;
}
```